# How to define style for rows of a GridView in WPF

Tags: c#, xaml

I am designing a GridView which is nested in a ListView. All things are fine but I want to apply some style on Row of GridView but cannot find predefined GridViewRow tag in xaml.

Actually I want to show lining at the borders of each row to show it separate.

```
<ListView  x:Name="gridTopics" BorderThickness="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TOPICSINFO}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="91,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="242" Width="310" BorderBrush="#FF32A3D6">
        <ListView.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF9ADDFB" />
        </ListView.Effect>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="GridViewControl">
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn  x:Name="colPageNo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PAGENO}" Width="50" Header="Pages" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colListTopics" Width="241" Header="Suggested Topics">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="colTopics" ItemsSource="{Binding LISTTOPICS}"
                                          SelectedIndex="0"
 />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a GridPanel to do this, it will allow you define and style rows and columns.

http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html